# Remove previous ID from Skype

Tags: skype

I am very new to Ubuntu.

When I installed Skype I used an old Id but I have a newer one that is exactly the same as my hotmail email. Every time I open Skype it is opened with the older ID but I would like to change this.

I can open another instance by using `skype --secondary` but I would like to remove the first one because I want to Lock to Launcher with the newer ID.

I read some forums telling about deleting the  `./Skype` folder but I don't know which folder that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `.Skype`, a hidden folder in the home directory.

Hit `ctrl+h` to reveal hidden folders, or run `rm -r .Skype` in a terminal window to remove it.

Comment: Thank you. How can I show hidden files by terminal (typing dir plus something)?

Comment: `dir -a`, or `ls -l`.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 20.04:

```sh
rm -r ~/.config/skypeforlinux/Local\ Storage
```